# Change keyboard in Grum

Tags: keyboard, password

I forgot my Ubuntu account password and tried to reset it using the grum menu (I followed this manual: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-hack-ubuntu-password/). However, since I have the Russian as my default keyboard, I can only type using Russian keys. Is there a way to change the keyboard layout while in the grum menu?

Comment: What is the grum menu?

Comment: If you're talking about `grub`, that runs before the actual OS is booted and uses features that exist within your machine firmware, thus you're limited mostly to whatever your firmware allows (*most firmware was originally written in US assuming ASCII thus assumes english keyboard; some default to other language/keyboards - but it's machine firmware specific*).  Why not boot & correct from *live* media (*thus allowing you to actually boot an OS*)